# Collection was modified; enumeration operation might not execute.'

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have this code where, whenever a condition is met, I'd insert a row to my datagridview. However, I'm met with the exception :

**Collection was modified; enumeration operation might not execute.**

Can anyone help me out?

Here's my code :

```
void connecttosql()
            {
                dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
                dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
                SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cn.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;Integrated Security=True"; // Changed
                cmd.Connection = cn;
                cmd.Connection.Open();
                cmd.CommandText = $"SELECT lot,item,toleranceMin,toleranceNom,toleranceMax,concernepar,donnees{comboBox1.Text+comboBox2.Text},{comboBox1.Text+comboBox2.Text} FROM Tolerance where {comboBox1.Text+comboBox2.Text} != ''"; // Changed
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();


                
              
                da.Fill(dt);

                int n = 0;

                DataColumn col = dt.Columns[$"donnees{comboBox1.Text + comboBox2.Text}"];
                foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {
                    string a = row[col].ToString();


                    if (int.Parse(a) > 3)
                    {
                        DataRow row1 = dt.NewRow();
                        dt.Rows.InsertAt(row1, n + 1);
                    }
                    n++;
                }
                BindingSource source = new BindingSource();
                source.DataSource = dt;


                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;


}
```

Comment: what can I change it to not infinitely add rows

Comment: `dt.Rows` doesn't contain a `ToList()` definition

Comment: You're iterating over the `dt.Rows` collection in a `foreach` loop, then you add elements to this collection, changing its enumeration; hence the exception

Answer (score 0):

As @Jimi stated, doing a loop over a collections enumerator (foreach .. in ..) will break as soon as you modify the list (e.g. add, remove).

In your case you could switch to a for-loop rather easily

```
foreach (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    string a = dt.Rows[i][col].ToString();

    if (int.Parse(a) > 3)
    {
        DataRow row1 = dt.NewRow();
        dt.Rows.Add(row1);
    }
}
```

Comment: I definitely can, I just didn't know it would give me a different outcome. Thanks for your help!